# shuffle unique images and call to form button-C#

Tags: c#

i'm building a poker game with classes.I have a class image where i want to load images from a string,shuffle and return unique images.After i want to call images to 5 picturebox in main.

this is in my class:

```
String[] img = Directory.GetFiles(@"...\...\cards");
List<int> deck = new List<int>();

public List<int> pachet1()
{
    Random rnd = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
    var lista = new List<int>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++)
    {
        deck.Add(i);
    }
    foreach (int a in deck)
    {
        int c = a;
        lista.Add(c);
    }
    return lista;
}
```

This is in main:

```
private void pictureBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //here i want to call fucntion
}
```

Comment: Why is this tagged c++?

Comment: And what is the question exactly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm undestanding you correctly you wish to shuffle then return 5 items from a list.

To do this you can use a generic `List` `shuffle` extension method.

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static void Shuffle<T>(this IList<T> list)
    {
        using (var provider = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            int n = list.Count;
            while (n > 1)
            {
                byte[] box = new byte[1];
                do provider.GetBytes(box);
                while (!(box[0] < n * (byte.MaxValue / n)));
                int k = (box[0] % n);
                n--;
                T value = list[k];
                list[k] = list[n];
                list[n] = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then use that to randomize the list and get the first `n` from the list.

```
public List<int> GetRandomItemsFromList(List<int>list, int amount)
{
    list.shuffle();
    return list.GetRange(0, amount);
}
```

And its usage is

```
List<int>items = GetRandomItemsFromList(list, 5);
```